# Upvoting a comment twice crashes app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-voting, android-app

Upvoting a comment is currently buggy, sometimes you see the number incrementing, sometimes nothing happens. There is no indication that a comment was voted on by oneself. Voting again when you have already voted on, however, crashes the app.

Tested twice on two different comments, with same effect.

I'm using Samsung S3 mini, model GT-I8190N, if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The app wasn't correctly handling the case when the server respondend with an error to comment voting. This is fixed in version 0.1.3 which I just uploaded to the Play Store, so it should be available within at most a few hours.

Comment: [Its back.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195059/200868)