# App crashes on upvoting a comment twice when not connected

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app, comment-voting

On upvoting a comment, without a connection, the operation fails silently with no error message. However, on upvoting again the app crashes. The second vote need not be on the same comment.

Version: 0.1.19

Answer (score 1):

As of an update before version 1.0 voting on comments comments now currently show error states and don't lead to any crashes.